# Connecting through SSH in VS Code crashes my web server

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code, web-development

I have a hosted web server and I would like to SSH to it from Visual Studio Code. I have a clean installation of it and the Remote SSH is literally the only plugin it uses.

I have created a SSH connection like this:

```
Host mywebserver.com
HostName mywebserver.com 
User username 
Port 123123
```

and successfully connected. I was surprised to see that while the connection was being established, VS Code was reporting that it was installing VS Code server, or something like that - I just wanted to SSH into the server, that is all. However, I thought that maybe VS Code needs to put some "little things" on the server, so I let it do its job.

In the end, I was able to log in and started editing my files as I needed to. Things were going smoothly for a while until suddenly, the server started throwing error 500. After looking into it, this was caused by numerous processes being run from `/home/myuser/.vscode-server/`. In fact, there was so many of them that they exceeded the limit for the number of processes of my webhosting, thus causing the error.

I have confirmed that in fact, when I am connected through SSH, it creates a lot of threads, and threads are actually limited to 50 by my hosting provider. This is what happens immediately when I connect:  https://pastebin.com/zH8uDqXu

How do I avoid this?

Comment: Were those processes or were they threads? (If you're checking via htop, threads show up green.)

Comment: I do not know - cPanel was saying "processes", but I don't know how exact its phrasing is. Also, htop is not installed on my system, I am using top.

Comment: I don't know what cPanel measures, but it's not uncommon to confuse task count with process count (on Linux a 'task' can be either a process or a thread) – especially as threads are indeed very much like processes that share memory... e.g. when `top` says it counts "tasks", it apparently means "processes". (Looks like pressing Shift+H in top will toggle the Task/Thread count in the top header, but I can't find a way to actually hide threads from the main list.) `ps x` would show processes, `ps xH` would show threads – on my system, I see RemoteSSH using 7 processes but probably 50-60 threads.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the actual maximum limit that cPanel shows on your server?

Comment: The limit displayed in cPanel is 50 processes. However, when I run top or ps x, there is only a few processes, usually 5-8. Running ps xH shows 30 threads, but at the same time, cPanel says there are 41 processes (or threads, difficult to say).

Comment: That really sounds like it counts tasks, then... and 50 is a very low limit. Even for a web server – the httpd service itself needs threads, NodeJS (which in this case powers the VSCode server) needs threads, etc. It's unfortunately typical for OpenVZ-based hosting, though.

Comment: Confirmed with the hosting provider that the limit is actually for the threads. I have also edited the question to show what ps xH shows when I connect through SSH.

Comment: Can you explain further precisely how you are setting up VSCode to use SSH and connect to this server? You have the connection info, but what in VSCode are you putting that connection info into? What happens when you use PuTTY or another SSH utility?

Comment: @music2myear: I'm 95% sure it's the built-in VSCode "[Remoting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh)" feature, which works by deploying half-of-VSCode on the server (as opposed to getting the files via SFTP) – so one would click the "Remote" button in the bottom-left corner, select "Connect to host (SSH)", enter the hostname, and then one would have a Node-based "vscode-server" process and any number of Node-based "VSCode extension worker" processes running on the server.

Comment: It is using the Remote-SSH plugin by Microsoft. Yes, it is the node-based thing.

Answer (score 1):

So the conclusion is that

1. the VSCode Remoting server starts *a few* processes (not many but still more than one), but the "numerous processes" shown by `top` are in fact threads, as most of those processes are copies of the highly-multithreaded Node JavaScript runtime (which runs various VSCode extensions on the server side), and each of those 5+ processes spawns its own 5–10 threads;
2. what cPanel calls "processes" is actually a limit on *threads* (or perhaps Linux 'tasks' that are the actual basis for both);
3. the hosting service is likely OpenVZ-based and sets a very strict limit on the number of threads per customer – just enough for the actual web server daemon and perhaps a webapp.

In this case, I would recommend doing the development on another server – preferably a full KVM-based VPS, where you have the entire OS all to yourself. These are more expensive than OpenVZ containers (which all share a single OS, that's what makes them cheap), but on the other hand you don't need as powerful a server for development as you might need for production.

So instead of directly hacking on the "live" website, you would remote into the private VPS and work there, then use Git (or SFTP) to deploy to the main server. (Not just because of threads; deploying via Git also means you'll *have* Git commits in the first place, which is a good thing to have whenever the website breaks and you need to quickly revert everything.)

Comment: Good point and I might do that, but in a more off-season period like during the summer holidays and such. But I would still like to know how to solve this for the time being. Maybe limit the number of threads used by VSCode server somehow.

Comment: That just seems to be the standard amount used by a `node` process, not something VSCode does specifically; you might be able to reduce it a little by setting `UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE=1` (down from 4) in the server-side environment (there might be a VSCode client-side setting to do that conveniently), but you can't really do anything about the other threads Node pre-creates for various specific tasks. (And avoid opening terminals inside VSCode – that goes through a whole separate Node process apparently.) If not a different server, then you'll probably have to use an VSCode SFTP plugin instead.

Comment: That is very helpful, thank you. Any good SFTP extension you might recommend? I was using some SFTP extension, but it was always opening files read-only and you had to take an extra step to make them editable, and that was driving me nuts.